# Webserver and websockets authentication

Tags: scala, session, playframework, websocket

I have a webserver on one computer and websockets on a different computer (but both in the same domain). I'm using Play framework 2.4.
I know I can authenticate websockets user based on the session created by the webserver (during initial handshake) when webserver and websockets are on the same computer.

But what if I want to do this on different computers?

Play framework uses secret key for encrypting sessions so could I just use the same security key on these two computers and just keep data in session (like user id) and decrypt them on websockets computer? (I'm new to this stuff but something is telling me it's not good idea to keep same secret keys on two computers). Or maybe should I send session data I received during websocket handshake to database to check user once more time? How is this usually done?

Comment: look at that maybe it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624216/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-to-deploy-play-framework-app-to-multiple-servers

Comment: Well, this indeed is helpful. Thanks salc2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701373/websockets-authentication)